# PowerBI Slicer Dynamic Default Value selection based on User Login

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, report, data-warehouse, dashboard

How can i configure PowerBI Slicer to Dynamically have Default Selected Values based on User Login.
i have a table for users configured with LOB

[image]

LOB is assigned to a Slicer in my reports, i want based on user login the LOB Slicer to have default selected values as configured in the table.

example if user2 logins:

[image]

if user1 logins:

[image]

etc...

your assistance is much appreciated
Georges Sabbagh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask is not directly possible in Power BI, but you can achieve something similar using [bookmarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-bookmarks). Leave the slicer in the report without any selection, then login as each user (or ask them to do it themselves) and create [personal bookmark](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-personal-bookmarks-in-the-power-bi-service/) with the desired items selected for the current user, and make this bookmark to be the default view. Now, whenever the user return to the report, this will override the persistent filter state (specified by you in the report) and land him in the view specified by the bookmark.

Comment: thank you it is simple way and helpfull, however it wont work on dashboards, is there any way to make it work for both reports and dashboards?

Comment: Not that I’m aware of

Comment: also i noticed that one Bookmark is only for 1 report page, i have several report pages, i want them all to have same bookmark, this wont work as well right?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what you are asking for is not possible, however you could work around this using [Row Level Security](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-username-in-dax-with-row-level-security/) (RLS)

Use the RLS to filter a table according to the logged in role. You can then use this in your PowerBI model to join with all the other roles and set a flag as to whether or not they are default.

You will end up with something like:

```
Function     | IsDefault
Motor        | Yes
Vehicle      | No
Casualty     | Yes
Ship         | No
```

You can then have your filter set on "IsDefault = Yes"

This will give the data filter you are looking for. When the user clears the "IsDefault = Yes" filter then all the other options will become available for selection.

Check out the RLS Blog I linked above, this should get you quite close.

Alternatively you can use [sync'd slicers](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/syncing-slicers-in-power-bi/) and have an initial "Start Page" report that a users has to select his role from on a drop down and this can be applied across all other reports due to the linking.

Comment: i am beginner in power bi, can you guide me using detailed steps? appreciate your assistance

Comment: @Murray Foxcroft Can you please check this?     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66525321/how-to-set-selected-value-from-slicer-to-api-in-powerbi?noredirect=1#comment117608816_66525321

Comment: I added some ideas as an answer @domahc